# how to get data from other methods?

Tags: java, variables

does anyone know how to get the counters value transfered after it is increased? so if you awnser it right it changes to one in the next method?

```
package swag;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void enter(){
        System.out.print("welcome to the impossibe game! Press enter to start.");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String enter = input.nextLine();    

        if (enter.equals("")){
            System.out.println("              Level one");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Please press enter");
        }
    }

    public static void firstlevel(){
        System.out.println("What is the tenth digit of PI?");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int awnser = input.nextInt();   
        int awnser1 = 5;
        int counter = 0;

        if (awnser == awnser1 ){
            System.out.println("Correct!");

            counter++;
            System.out.println("            Score:   " +counter + "/1");

        }else{
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
            System.out.println("            Score:"+ counter+"/1");
        }   
    }

    public static void secondlevel(){
        System.out.println("a king and queen get on a boat. then the boat sinks. how many people are alive");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String awnser = input.nextLine();

        if (awnser.equals("two ")){
            System.out.println("      Correct!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        enter();
        firstlevel();
    }
}
```

Comment: please look at your post, notice that it looks all wrong, and fix it. The "how to ask questions" page tells you to proof read your post before posting it. That's not there for giggles, people need to actually be able to read your post =)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the way you have defined counter, it can only be seen in firstLevel.

Best thing to do is make it a 'class variable'. To do that:

1. Delete `int counter = 0;` from the firstLevel method.
2. Add `static int counter = 0;` on the very next line after `public class Main {`

So the start of your class should look like:

```
public class Main {
    static int counter = 0;
```

Now counter will be visible in all methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend not using a static counter, as suggested by others. Static mutable objects tend to violate the principle of object oriented programming. If you separate the functionality of your game into methods, you'll have a much more beautiful main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Lets create a new Game object. it will keep track of the counter itself!
    Game game = new Game();
    // Then we only have to call the methods defined below..
    game.enter();
    game.firstLevel();
    game.secondlevel();
}
```

Now the code for the class `Game` containing all the logic:

```
public class Game {
    // Some static final members. they are not meant to change throughout the execution of the program!
    // The advantage of defining INDENTAION just once, is that you can easily change it in one place and it will always be consistent!
    private static final String INDENTAION = "\t\t";
    private static final int TOTAL_POINTS = 2;
    // We can use the same scanner object in each method!
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Just like the counter. it will be accessible in each method and refer to the same integer!
    private int counter = 0;

    public void enter() {
        System.out.print("welcome to the impossibe game! Press enter to start.");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String enter = input.nextLine();

        if (enter.equals("")) {
            System.out.println(INDENTAION + "Level one");
        } else {
            // I am not sure why you put this here, but I'll leave it in for now
            System.out.println("Please press enter");
        }
    }

    // We put that code into seperate methods, since it will get called multiple times!
    private void answerCorrect() {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        counter++;
        printScore();
    }

    private void answerWrong() {
        System.out.println("Wrong!");
        printScore();
    }

    private void printScore() {
        System.out.println(INDENTAION + "Score: " + counter +"/"+ TOTAL_POINTS);
    }

    public void firstLevel() {
        System.out.println("What is the tenth digit of PI?");
        int awnser = input.nextInt();

        if (awnser == 5) {
            answerCorrect();
        }else{
            answerWrong();
        }
    }

    public void secondlevel() {
        System.out.println("a king and queen get on a boat. then the boat sinks. how many people are alive");
        String awnser = input.nextLine();

        if (awnser.equals("two") || awnser.equals("2")) {
            answerCorrect();
        } else {
            answerWrong();
        }
    }
}
```